# Value of string to be a trigger

Tags: python, function, syntax

I'm trying to get my code to get a string of data from a sensor, and then do something when it reads a specific value.

The following code is how I'm receiving the data now (this is just a test) the function is called earlier in the code at the time where I want it to be called.

```
def gettemperature(self)
    temp = self.board.temp_sensor
    print("Temperature is " + str(round(temp)) + " degrees.")
```

This code works, and returns the temperature value rounded to the terminal, but how could I, instead of printing the value to the terminal, make it so when that string of rounded value is say, 200 degrees, then it prints the temperature value? instead of printing it every 2 seconds (the frequency of the data being received, as per another part of the code)

Using something like

```
if temp = 200 
then print(blahblah)
```

in short, the above code is what I'm trying to do. If the temp equals a certain value, then something else will happen.

That last code doesn't work. I'm pretty new to coding, so I'm assuming I'm either not going about this the right way, or the syntax of how I'm going about trying to get that value to do something isn't correct (obviously)

Thanks for any help! I'm surprised I got this far, haha.

Comment: `if temp == 200: print(temp)`. Note the double `==`

Comment: I'm surprised you learned about functions _before_ you learned about `if` statements and equality checks. My recommendation is that you should do some tutorials to get comfortable with the basics first.

Comment: @BTables that worked! Thank you.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi this code was pre written by someone else, and I'm just modifying it to do some other things at the same time. I'm basically just learning the things I need to learn in order to add the things I'm interested in adding. But I've had a lot of fun doing these (Relatively mild) alterations, so I'm gonna do some more learning just about the basics and stuff, away from this project.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if your function gettemperature would return something and then print the result in the condition:

```
def gettemperature()
    temp = board.temp_sensor
    return temp


temp = gettemperature()

if temp == 200:
    print("Temperature is " + str(round(temp)) + " degrees.")
```

Comment: My goal is to have it send an email (for now using smtplib) when temp == a specific value. I'm just using the print command to test my theory before I flood my inbox with messages. 

I think I like this structure better, and am going to try it. The only issue I have to figure out now is if there's a way to only perform the print function when temp == a rounded specific value, or at least a range of specific decimal values. The temperature from the sensor is inputted every 2 seconds, in a decimal which is necessary for other parts of the code, but for this, I just need the integer value.

Comment: temp = int(gettemperature()) will convert to an integer value

Answer (score 0):

Before using stackoverflow, I'd recommend learning all this stuff from some basic course, as you'll get to learn the stuff yourself rather then get the answer from someone else.
Try learning conditional statements.
what you want is, to put a conditional statement which triggers if temperature is greater than 200.

If the temp is always a number in string data type, you can use the below code.

```
def gettemperature(self):
    temp = self.board.temp_sensor
    print("Temperature is " + str(round(temp)) + " degrees.")
    temp=int(temp) #typecasting string datatype to integer
    if temp == 200:
        print("Temperature is high")
```

Comment: Thank you! 

Like I mentioned in a comment above, I really only started messing with this to add more things to an already written code, and have just been learning the things I need to make those changes, but I've enjoyed learning this and figuring all this out more than I thought I would, so I do intend to go back from the beginning and learn the basics apart from this specific project.